# How do I deploy a Node.js HTTP/2 application onto Google Compute Engine using a Docker image?

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, http2

This used to work until a week ago, when the VM ran out of memory due to a missing finally in a try-catch. So, I tried to re-deploy with this fix to a new instance and now nothing is working.

Here is the git repository of the server: https://gitlab.com/pumpkin-spice-latte/psl-server

I use the GCP console shell to build and push the image. It is on the VM with the container available and running. However, when I try to connect to the external IP address, nothing is there. 
https://35.203.160.44/

Here is a screenshot of the `docker ps` & `docker images`:
[docker-ps-docker-images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKqX7.png)

Here is a screenshot of the `Firewall Rules`:
[firewall-rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyL9T.png)

Halp!!!! lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cloned the repo locally and found a typo in the port:

```
const PORT =
  process.env.PORT || (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 8443 : 433); // should be 443
```

I think you meant 443 instead of 433.

Comment: Thank you! The port is published on that instance though which is why I find all of this super confusing. Unless there is something extra I need to do to get it "published." I added another image with the firewall rules.

Comment: @PumpkinSpice The PORTS column in `docker ps` output is empty which indicates the ports aren't published. What's the `docker run` command that you used to start the container? did you add `-p 443:443` to it?

Comment: I just load in the container using the standard UI input on GCP which automatically runs the container for me. Do you know if there is a way for me to append the port to it? Again, thank you very much! You are such a great help :)

Comment: Ah I just [found out](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers#publishing_container_ports) that GCP runs containers using --network="host" so you don't need to publish the port. So that's not the issue, hmm... Looking at the commit logs I can't find any obvious changes between previous deploy that might cause this. Other than the `--expose-http2` flag, maybe give it a try without it? Otherwise I'll have pull your repo and try running it myself to figure out more.

Comment: I added that in to try to fix the problem haha but, I'll try removing it

Comment: Honestly, I think I'm missing a configuration somehow. I don't know how since I just followed the GCP docs. haha The logs don't say anything is wrong. It logs that the server is listening on port 443. I seriously don't understand what's wrong. Could it just be the size of the instance?

It's an e2-mirco with 1GB of memory.

Comment: If the VM size was too small for the container I would expect it to yell and not fail silently. It also doesn't match with being able to ssh into it, see it running, logs looking ok. Did the IP address change perhaps?

Comment: @PumpkinSpice Found a typo in the port when I tried to run it locally. I've updated my answer. Is that the issue?

Comment: That might be the issue, but I think it says that it's running on port 443. Let me check the logs again! If that is the problem, then THANK YOU SO MUCH :D YOU ARE AMAZE LOL